# Windows Programming: pWnd and HWND difference

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

Why would some functions in Windows require a `pWnd` parameter while others require `HWND` parameter? Example:

```
// Get a dc for a CWnd object pointer.
CPaintDC dc(pWnd);
// Send my private massage.
::SendMessage(pWnd->m_hWnd, WM_MYMESSAGE, (LPARAM) &dc.m_ps, 0);
```

Actually, why would Windows have both types `pWnd` and `HWND`?

Since `HWND` can be get via `pWnd->m_hWnd`, the functions can always can always take `pWnd` as a parameter. What is the design philosophy behind it?

Comment: My guess (and it is just a guess) is that some APIs that take HWND came first and were maintained for backward compatibility.  Later APIs used the pWnd construct, which encapsulates the HWND but also provides more information.

Comment: The first function is MFC specific so it can require a MFC specific parameter.  The second is not a MFC function so it can't.

Comment: BTW, you could use a CWnd wrapper for Send message, like this: `pWnd->SendMessage(WM_MYMESSAGE, (LPARAM) &dc.m_ps, 0);`

Comment: @Eric You may wish to stop guessing in the future. In particular if you have not the least bit of a clue on the topic at hand. There is not a single Windows API that requires a `CWnd` - or even any C++ class for that matter. The Windows API has a C interface. `CWnd` is part of a class library (like MFC, or WTL, or something else).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not a single function in Windows that takes a `CWnd*` (which you call `pWnd`).  Windows (in particular, `user32.dll`) uses exclusively `HWND` to identify window objects.

`class CWnd` is part of MFC, which is a C++ library built on top of Windows.  Only MFC and classes and functions written using MFC will even know what that is.

(And then there's Modern UI formerly-known-as-Metro, which has none of the above.  It doesn't use `user32.dll` either.  But that's another topic.)